# JavaScript Window Object has Infinity value available

Tags: javascript, window, infinity

I printed out the global `window` object the other day to find that the first value was `Infinity`. Can anyone provide any reason, or references as to why this is here? I've done a bit of research, but haven't turned up any good answers.

[image]

I can see from MDN that infinity is always part of the global `window`, but I'm just wondering how/why someone would use it? I know this is a general question, but I'm hoping I can get a well-formed answer to help me understand how/when I should be utilizing `Infinity`.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity

Comment: All I can offer is that JS returns `Infinity` as the value of division by zero, where other languages throw an error. `1/0 == Infinity`. I expect this is a legacy of Old JavaScript's make-everything-legal philosophy.

Comment: Sometimes it's useful to have a value that you know is greater (or less) than any finite number. `var arr = [-10, 25, -296, 19452]; var smallest = arr.reduce(function(min, curr) { return Math.min(min, curr); }, Infinity);`

Answer (score -1):

This is done for you to use it.
How would you assign an Infinity value to any of your variables if there wasn't such variable?